# Execute both exec ports in the same frame

Tags: c++, blueprints, unreal-5

I made the following:

[image]

Notice the [Button] node has two execute ports.
The `CLICKED` exec port is executed when a button is clicked. The other exec port is supposed to always execute. But right now it executes always except when the button is clicked.

Right now I have:

```c
UENUM(BlueprintType)
enum class EButton : uint8
{
    NONE,
    CLICKED
};
```

```c
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "ImGui", Meta = (ExpandEnumAsExecs = "Branches"))
    static void Button(FString text, EButton& Branches);
```

```c
void UImGuiComponent::Button(FString text, EButton& Branches)
{

    if (ImGui::Button(FString_to_char_pointer(text))) {
        Branches = EButton::CLICKED;
    }
    else {
        Branches = EButton::NONE;
    }
}
```

How can it be controlled that multiple exec output ports are (not) executed.
I'm looking for a solution in c++, please.